# Salesforce Console: How can you get subtab ID by its name?

Tags: service-cloud-console, console, consoleintegrationtoolkit, custom-service-console

I'm hoping to override/refresh a particular subtab if it already exists, or open it as a new subtab if it doesn't exist yet.

However I can't seem to find a way to get subtabs by name. The console integration toolkit gives you `sforce.console.getSubtabIds(...)` but the resulting IDs don't tell me whether its the particular subtab I need.

Any help/suggestions?

Comment: How did you determine which subtab based on the below answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uou can use openSubtab() method, which creates as well as overrides subtab.

```
sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId , 'http://www.salesforce.com', false, 'salesforce', null, openSuccess, 'salesforceSubtab');
```

> Opens a new subtab (within a primary tab) that displays the content of
>   a specified URL, which can be relative or absolute. You can also
>   override an existing subtab. Use to open a new subtab on a primary tab
>   via the primary tab's ID. This method is only available in API version
>   20.0 or later.

You can Refer the same in [Salesforce Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_opensubtab.htm)

Comment: I don't understand how does this help determine the tab that he wants to refresh on? @jmrjulian